# Criteria API - ANY operator with expression as right-hand value

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I would like to achieve query such as the one below using `CriteriaBuilder`:

```
select v.key, v.value from entity e inner join entity_variables v on e.id = v.entity_id where key = 'someKey' and 'acceptableValue' = any (cast(v.value as varchar[]))
```

ANY operator as per it's definition compares left-hand value using provided operator against all values provided by right-hand subquery OR expression but `Criteria API`'s `CriteriaBuilder` for some reason does not allow providing `Expression` for ANY operator as it only accepts `Subquery` for `CriteriaBuilder::any` method.

Is it possible to generate such query using `CriteriaBuilder`s API?

Comment: Once that you have the query in a clear readable standard language why not use it natively rather than have it smudged and obfuscated by using CriteriaBuilder?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm current implementation is based on Criteria API and so I don't have much choice but to use it - other option is to completely re-write query engine but that would be costly option. I've been using CriteriaBuilder many times, this is the first time I got stuck.